# Can't convert lead to opportunity, company issue

Tags: odoo, crm

I can't convert a lead to an opportunity.

Both the lead and the partner/customer are set to the same company: Company 1.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Incompatible companies on records:

'Lead 1' belongs to company False and 'Customer' (partner_id: 'customer_1@mail.com') belongs to another company.
```

I can only convert a lead to an opportunity if I set the company of the partner/customer to empty.

Comment: The error shows that the lead and customer are not in the same company, the lead is shared between all companies because company is  ```False``` and the customer in another company (Not the one which you are using to convert the lead to opportunity)
So you have two solutions: Log in to the other company and convert the lead or set the customer company to empty (means the customer will be shared for all companies). BTW Odoo allow you to set the customer of lead for shared customers or customers in the same company. I don't how this happen with you.

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I'm not sure to be honest. The problem goes away only if I change the company_id field of the partner/customer of that lead to empty.

Comment: What is the Odoo version you are using?

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I'm using Odoo v15